# Not able to locate the DMG image to make macos catalina bootable usb

Tags: macos

I have a mac mini where i am trying to make a bootable usb with macos catalina on it.
but trouble is since the latest big sur release you cannot find the .DMG file of older OS any where.

I tried searcing in search engines and no luck.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to this link: https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201372
here you can find the OS of your choice.
I have a mac machine in which i got this link: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-catalina/id1466841314?mt=12 which redirects me to the macos appstore to download Catalina directly.

Give it a try. (I am able to Download the .DMG file successfully)

Comment: Exactly how did you get a .dmg file? macOS installers normally download as applications. The app *used* to contain a .dmg that could be copied to a USB disk as a bootable installer, but that's no longer the case.